# Add OpenSSL static lib to Visual Studio 2017 project

Tags: c++, openssl, visual-studio-2017, nuget

Do NuGets modify the include and linking paths when added to a project?

My background is with CMake where this stuff was trivial, but I'm now at a company that builds solution files from the ground up and I'm unsure how to properly add the static OpenSSL libs to my project.  I'm posting the question to make sure I don't duplicate something or otherwise mess it up.

When I add the [openssl-vc141-static-x86_64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/openssl-vc141-static-x86_64/) to my project, it builds the `.lib` files and everything, but does not modify the include or linker paths.

I can manually add the linker paths, but because the project I was given doesn't have the typical `Release`/`Debug` configurations, I can't use the `$(Configuration)` macro to point at the target libs - so I end of just pointing at `Release`.  The build works though.

I see there is a `.targets` file, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

(*update*)

To be specific, I'm basically building boost's [http_server_async.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/beast/example/http/server/async/http_server_async.cpp).  The linker errors I'm getting are:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _BIO_free referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::context::bio_cleanup::~bio_cleanup(void)" (??1bio_cleanup@context@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ) ESOIPDataScope  C:\gitrepo\ALIDB\ESOIPDataScope\DataHandler.obj 
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _BIO_free    ESOIPDataScope  C:\gitrepo\ALIDB\ESOIPDataScope\Listener.obj
... (48 more like this)
```

When I manually add `$(SolutionDir)packages\openssl-vc141-static-x86_64.1.1.0\build\native\lib\Win32\static\Release\libcrypto.lib` and 
`$(SolutionDir)packages\openssl-vc141-static-x86_64.1.1.0\build\native\lib\Win32\static\Release\libssl.lib` to be additional dependencies the project compiles.

(/*update*)

Just for contrast, I added a freeglut NuGet, and noticed that gave my more configuration options (Configuration Properties → Referenced Projects), also, boost seems to have added its linker directories to my project (though I only see that in MSBuild output, not in Configuration Properties->Linker->Command Line)

Is there a proper way to add these projects that I'm missing?  Or a proper way to use the `targets` file?  Or maybe the OpenSSL static NuGet just missing something?  Or maybe I should just look into vcpkg?

Comment: l think when you use nuget package to install the library, you do not need to care the `include path` or anything else about the configuration of environment. It will be configured automatically through `<package_id>.targets` file  although this function does not show in the project property UI. You can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) to learn the custom build targets or properties.

Comment: You can enter the target file and will find the `<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>` and `<AdditionalDependencies>` which contains the new library path. Besides, I wonder if you face any errors when you install this nuget package into project.  In my side, l can use its header file directly after l install the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do NuGets modify the include and linking paths when added to a
>   project?

**Sure**. I can tell you explicitly that the nuget imports additional properties into the project through `<package_id>.targets` or `<package_id>.props` file, instead of manually adding include path again.

This is a mechanism for nuget packaging to add additional project properties such as library path directly to the project during the installation of the nuget package. More info you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package).

The `<package_id>.targets` was created during the process of packing the nuget package.
In other words, this method was designed by the author of the nuget package. And in my side, the file `openssl-vc141-static-x86_64.targets` exists in this path:

```
C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\ConsoleApplication25\packages\openssl-vc141-static-x86_64.1.1.0\build\native
```

> also, boost seems to have added its linker directories to my project
>   (though I only see that in MSBuild output, not in Configuration
>   Properties->Linker->Command Line)

l think the issue is related to the difference between `<package_id>.targets` and `<package_id>.props`. Although using `<package_id>.targets` does not appear on the property UI, it still works for the whole project.

**In more detail**

When you install the nuget package into the project, these files are automatically executed. `<target_id>.props` file is added at the top of the file while .targets is added at the bottom.

When initializing the `xxx.vcxproj` file, because `<package_id> .props` is at the head of the file, the property UI can capture the properties in the file, and `<package_id> .targets` is at the end, so the initialization cannot be captured but still In the project. For the nuget, it uses `openssl-vc141-static-x86_64.targets`.

In `openssl-vc141-static-x86_64.targets` file, you can see this:

```
<ClCompile>
        <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)include\;% 
           (AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
        <PreprocessorDefinitions>HAS_LIBTHRIFT;%(PreprocessorDefinitions) 
        </PreprocessorDefinitions>
</ClCompile>
```

And l have set the output log to `Diagnostic` and build the project and found this:

[image]

The library path has been added into `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` by the `openssl-vc141-static-x86_64.targets` file automatically. So you do not have to worry about it.

> Is there a proper way to add these projects that I'm missing? Or a
>   proper way to use the targets file? Or maybe the OpenSSL static NuGet
>   just missing something? Or maybe I should just look into vcpkg?

You do not need to worry about it and do not add the include path into project property. This is superfluous and when you have finished installing this nuget package, use it in cpp files directly.

**In addition**,

For c++ packages installed by nuget, you don't need to add any paths to the project property.

**Update 1**

The issue is related to your project rather than the nuget package. Exactly because your current project does not have `$(Configuration)`, so in `openssl-vc141-static-x86_64.targets`, you can see these：

```
 <ItemDefinitionGroup Label="Win32 and vc141 and Debug" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'Win32' And ( $(PlatformToolset.IndexOf('v141')) &gt; -1 Or '$(PlatformToolset)' == 'WindowsKernelModeDriver8.0' Or '$(PlatformToolset)' == 'WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.0' Or '$(PlatformToolset)' == 'WindowsUserModeDriver8.0' ) And '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
          <Link>
              <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)lib\Win32\static\Debug\;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
        <AdditionalDependencies>libssl.lib;libcrypto.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
          </Link>
      <PostBuildEvent>
        <Command>xcopy /Y "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\lib\Win32\dynamic\*-1_1.dll" "$(OutDir)"</Command>
      </PostBuildEvent>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

This is the operation to import specific `libssl.lib` and `libcrypto.Lib` into the `AdditionalDependencies` node. But you can find out that there is a judge condition `And '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'`, since you do not have `$(Configuration)`,therefore, it always returns **false** and these libs cannot be automatically imported into `AdditionalDependencies`.

**As a workaround**, you should add these lib path manually just as you said.

And l am sure that if you use a project which contains `$(Configuration)`(Debug or Release), you will not encouter this issue. And most of the C++ nuget packages can be used directly in the project which contains the `Configuration` node.

l am sure that if you use the `$(Configuration)` into your project and then reinstall this package(please [clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) before doing it), you will not face this error.

> Also, your screen shot, where did you get that? I don't see anything
>   like that in the VS output console, or when I run msbuild on the
>   command line. Is there some way I might have accidentally broken the
>   default behaviour?

You can set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Diagnostic` by `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Projects and Solutions`-->`Build and Run`.

When you build your project,the **Output Window** shows thw whole build process and records all the information and then you can search the key fields by the **search box** on the **Output Window**.

Comment: This is a extremely well written answer.  I still have the same issue though.  I modified the question above to show the linker errors I get when I don't manually add the links to libssl and libcrypto.  They manifest in the form of boost asio errors, but adding the links fixes them.  Also, your screen shot, where did you get that?  I don't see anything like that in the VS output console, or when I run msbuild on the command line.  Is there some way I might have accidentally broken the default behaviour?  When I look at my vcxproj file, I see openssl there in the `ExtensionTargets` section

Comment: I think your issue is related to your project which does not contain `$(Configuration)` rather than the nuget package. The one job for `openssl-vc141-static-x86_64.targets` is use the `$(Configuration)` to judge and then add these libs into `AdditionalDependencies` node. Since you do not have this node, this step cannot be executed and you should add them manually.  When you projects which contain  `$(Configuration)`, you will not face these problems. You can check `Update 1`.

Comment: That was it!  I removed the `DebugU` and `ReleaseU` configurations importing this project inserted into my solution file, and now when I build the static bindings work!  This also removed a weird boost asio flags warning I was getting too.  Thanks!